# Accidentally removed internal disk before High Sierra installation

Tags: macos, disk-utility, install, diskutil, high-sierra

I have a 15" mid-2014 MacBook Pro (with a 256GB SSD). Today I wanted to install macOS High Sierra, so I created a bootable USB installation drive. Then I booted into the installer and fired up Disk Utility to wipe my internal disk. I erased the disk and created a new APFS partition. Accidentally, I clicked on the "Remove Volume" icon. Now my internal disk is completely gone from Disk Utility. That's why I can't select it as a target for High Sierra and start the installation.

In a terminal, `diskutil list` still shows the disk with two partitions I created earlier (it also shows lots of disk images, but I assume this is not related):

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         125.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         125.4 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +125.4 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +125.4 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *15.5 GB    disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Install macOS High S... 15.2 GB    disk3s2

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk4
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk4s1

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +12.6 MB    disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk19

/dev/disk20 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk20

/dev/disk21 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk21

/dev/disk22 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk22

/dev/disk23 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 GB     disk23
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 USB                     4.0 GB     disk23s1
```

Here's the output of `diskutil info`:

```
   Device Identifier:        disk0
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0
   Whole:                    Yes
   Part of Whole:            disk0
   Device / Media Name:      APPLE SSD SM0256F

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 PCI
   SMART Status:             Verified

   Disk Size:                251.0 GB (251000193024 Bytes) (exactly 490234752 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:          Internal
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Solid State:              Yes
   Virtual:                  No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

Any idea what's wrong with my SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I erased the disk and created an AFPS partition. Apparently, this only creates a container, in which the actual partition must be added. I deleted the containers using the `diskutil afps` commands and then erased the disk by creating a new HFS+ partition.

In summary, if you want to install High Sierra from scratch, boot from the installation USB drive, start Disk Utility and erase/format your target drive with GUID/HFS+ (the previous default). The installer will then automatically convert it to APFS during the installation process.